# Hamcrest Contains Matcher

Tags: json, rest-assured, matcher, hamcrest

So my problem is presenting as a type-matching of sorts;

I have code that queries a database, and returns an array of string type. When I attempt to validate against my JSON message returned from a web service, one of the values is a primitive integer (without the double-quotes), and the validation is failing, as it is stating: **Expected: iterable containing {"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"}Actual: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]**I'm using the contains matcher to validate a ListArray of values against many returned by the query. My assumption is that the **Actual** is being evaluated as an integer, but the values to validate against (**Expected**) are String. I've been racking my brain attempting the HasToString or hasItem matchers but I think that would just parse toString if the target is a single value.I guess my ultimate question is, is there a way to force Hamcrest to evaluate the JSON data as a String, or implicitly/explicitly cast the Expected to the evaluated type?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you put Strings in the expected value? That would solve everything and is the simplest, clearest and best approach. Modifying actuals to conform with expecteds in a different format is a slippery slope, because you run the risk of the conversion hiding problems; your situation is simple but it's bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: @Bohemian, That was the problem, the expected value(s) were String, it was the actual that was being evaluated as ArrayList<Integer>, so the matcher just wasn't sure what do do with it. I wish I could avoid it, but our JSON objects return different types...

Answer (score 0):

So, I acutally think I figured this one out; what I ended up doing was performing a **toString().** on the extracted ArrayList of objects, which gave me string values; code example below:

```
ArrayList<String> myObj = response.path(jsonField);
String[] myObjStr = new String[myObj.size()];
int x = 0;
        for (Object obj : myObj){
            myObjStr[x] = obj.toString();
            x++;
        }
```

From there, I was able to compare the resulting arrays; Now if only I could figure out how to get rid of pesky angle brackets for nested elements...